# Microsoft Visual Studio | Redirect users to a website from clicking a button inside the software

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I am completely new to creating software applications and I was wondering how to send users to a website when clicking a button. Like they do it in other software. I am using visual basic code (vb)

Comment: Alldone. Hopefully its good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this (WPF):

```
Try
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.AppStarting
    Process.Start("http://example.com/")
Finally
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing
End Try
```

or this (WinForms):

```
Try
    Dim temp = Me.Cursor
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Process.Start("http://example.com/")
Finally
    Me.Cursor = temp
End Try
```

Adapted from here:

> http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/01/using_processstart_to_link_to/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ShellExecute` facilities for that (see [this MSDN article for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)).

basically what you do is call the `Shell.ShellExecute` and provide it with the URL you want to be opened - the OS will open it in currently configured default browser (which is a nice added bonus from the user interaction point of view)